# CSS for JavaFX application in IntelliJ for free

Tags: gratis, java, css

I have designed a JavaFX project in IntelliJ but now I have encountered a problem. The software that I am making is totally free and I wish to distribute it as a learning experience. Because of this I don't want to pay $500 for software when I am most likely never going to earn that money back. Is it possible to still use CSS? I am willing to move the project to another IDE if necessary, I just want to be able to style my application.

Answer (score 0):

I never got far enough into JavaFX during my programming class to care about much beyond an inline style or two (I'm a back end guy), but I used Netbeans 8.2 w/ JDK 1.8 and SceneBuilder 2.0 on my LinuxMint desktop.  SceneBuilder 2.0 has a CSS Analyzer and can import or create new style sheets for a given scene.

You can run SceneBuilder 2.0 as a stand alone application BUT I'm not sure if it needs other parts of Netbeans installed to really function and do its thing, or how well it would integrate with the project structure of another IDE.

You can download it from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html

[image]

Comment: Then the problem that I run into is exporting my IntelliJ project to NetBeans. I feel somewhat stuck.

Comment: @joshLor I don't think you'd need to - if you just open the FXML file with Scene Builder it should work and put the style references into the FXML file and generate a style sheet file (maybe?).  Once that is done, go back to IntelliJ and see what you get.  Certainly worth experimenting with on a low-risk demo project (simple hello world thing)